# Url insertion in ES6 Template literlals

Tags: javascript, url, ecmascript-6, escaping

I have a Json file containing many objects and I want to display them using the template literals syntax in ES6. I need to display a set of images but cant passes any URL because it seems to delete the // of the address.  Else everything works perfectly.

The problem seems to come from the innerHTML function because when I console log the variable containing the HTML code to be inserted the URL is written perfectly.

I would like to figure out how to fix this and display my images correctly

( the HTML inside the template literal is way longer, I just simplified it for here )

```
 const resultat = document.querySelector('.master-wrapper'); //where the result appear

    const html = pokedex.map(pokedex => {
        return `
                <img src"  ${ pokedex.img } "></img>  //where the url is inserted
               `;
    }).join('')

    resultat.innerHTML += html;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `=` sign here and because of that the browser renders it as separate attributes removing the slashes.

```
<img src="  ${ pokedex.img } "></img>  //where the url is inserted
```

Comment: i would delete the whitespace inside of `src`.

Comment: Thank you that seems so stupid now, i was trying to escape the charachter, use raw-string ...